# Is it reasonable for dupes to appear before the non-dupe in search results?

Tags: discussion, search, duplicate-questions, sorting

If you search Stack Overflow for `[c++] static block`, you get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20static%20block) (as of 2021-11-08):

1. Q: What is static block in c or c++? [duplicate]
2. Q: Static blocks in C++ [duplicate]
3. Q: What's the C++ idiom equivalent to the Java static block?
4. A: What is the effect of extern "C" in C++?

and so on.

Items 1 and 2 are duplicates of item 3. Is it reasonable for them to appear before the non-dupe?

Notes:

- Naturally I'm asking about searches in general, not just this example.
- I assume the order of the results in the example has something to do with the shorter titles of the dupes, which have less non-matching terms, although I'm not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help us find duplicates efficiently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279852/282094)

Comment: @bad_coder: That's related, but it seems to be about a specific bug which has been resolved.

Comment: The search functionality is fairly garbage, so I fear answering "is it reasonable?" to most aspects of it a trick question, since the answer is probably "no".