# Duplicate search results are disappointing, can we fix this?

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-questions, duplicate-suggestions

On the Android site, I wanted to close a question as a duplicate of another I was familiar with.  In the close dialog, I typed `where can i find stock or custom roms for my android device`, expecting to find [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465).

Instead, it was 9th in the list.  All of the results above it were closed as duplicates of it, and the highest score any had was 7 (as opposed to 69 for the one I wanted).

Regular search results from the bar at the top of the site return it first, as one would expect.  So I have a few questions:

1. Why does the dupe search behave differently if it's not better for its intended task?  This is the most egregious case I've seen, but I can't recall a time when I wasn't frustrated with the results.
2. Why does the duplicate search even show closed questions?  At best, you're creating an annoying chain; at worst, you're just screwing the asker over.
3. If a question has lots of duplicates pointing to it, [shouldn't the results rank it highly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232131/boost-duplicate-post-search-results-by-incoming-link-count)?  Apparently [we need to go back to 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104849/154510).
4. Honestly, how can searching *the exact title* not make it the first result?

Comment: Thanks guys, I saw one that was a bit related but did not stumble across the marked dupe; I'll follow it instead!