# Augment search with a duplicate-target keyword or similar

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-questions

Often when I search for the duplicate when voting to close as duplicate, the duplicate target I search for has been used as duplicate before. So one way to search for dupe-targets (or maybe reverse-duplicates) would be very helpful.

*Please implement some search feature.*

A similar question was asked before: [Boost duplicate-post search results by incoming link count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232131/boost-duplicate-post-search-results-by-incoming-link-count).